increase max connection in redsocks linux
hi i have a busy server and want increase max_conn more than 128 in redsocks there is any way more connection here is something but i was unsuccessful to change 128 max_conn in redsocks
https://github.com/darkk/redsocks/blob/master/redsocks.conf.example
// listenq = 128; // SOMAXCONN equals 128 on my Linux box.
what is this line

review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux

hi i use this configuration and speed get wild
base {
log_debug = off;
log_info = off;
log = stderr;
daemon = on;
redirector = iptables;
redsocks_conn_max = 4096;
connpres_idle_timeout = 7440;
max_accept_backoff = 6000;
}

redsocks {
local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
local_port = 12345;
listenq = 4096;
splice = true;
ip = 127.0.0.1;
port = 10808;
type = socks5;
}


Some explanation what this config is doing and how it resolves the question that was asked will make this an answer. Right now it is a comment, as there is nothing contextually linking your info here to the question (you) asked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
